# State Machine Workflow - Event Driven - Requires State Transition?

Tags: workflow-foundation

Within a state machine, if an event is handled within an event driven activity, is it required that a state transition (i.e. SetStateActivity) occur?

My goal is to allow the same logic within the particular event driven activity to occur repeatedly (by being signaled multiple times) until a certain condition is met at which time the state should transition and the process would repeat for the next state.

Currently, in the case that a state transition does not occur, it looks like the event driven activity completes and then the entire workflow completes as well (i.e. all activities are closed), but when looking at the tracking data, the workflow instance indicates that it was terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsworkflowfoundation/thread/cef8300a-fbf0-47e6-b4f9-e444343208e3/